# How to find 2 consecutive words, but counting only the shortest string

Tags: notepad++, find, find-and-replace

I want to be able to search in Notepad++ for a string that begins with a `[startWord]` and ends with an `[endWord]`.

Additional conditions:

1. the `[startWord]` and `[endword]` can each only appear once in the string;
2. the search should return the shortest string that meets the criteria`

##### Example

`[startWord]`: cat     `[endWord]`: dog

```
# Text to search

The DOG walks in an alley.
The CAT walks down the street.
The CAT loves sardines,
but when the CAT sees a shadow
which can only be that of a DOG,
the CAT runs away from the supposed DOG.
```

The search result should be

```
CAT runs away from the supposed DOG
```

How would I perform that search in Notepad++

Comment: ..."but counting only the last cat word, and the first dog word that occurs after it.", then how can the result be "CAT sees a shadow which can only be that of a DOG" when the last cat and first dog after it is in "CAT runs away from the supposed DOG"?

Comment: Find: `CAT(?:(?!CAT|DOG)[\s\S])+DOG`

Comment: @BlindSpots: I understand the question as the last `CAT` of a serie of `CAT`s. When you see the expected result given by OP i.e. `cat sees a shadow which can only be that of a dog`, it is clear. My regex `CAT(?:(?!CAT|DOG)[\s\S])+DOG` can't be shortened to `CAT(?:(?!CAT)[\s\S])+DOG` they are completly different, they don't match same thing. Just test both and you will see.

Comment: @BlindSpots: There are differences for sentences like `blah blah CAT blah DOG blah DOG blah`, i.e. multiple `DOG`s without `CAT` in between. I don't know if it's possible in OP's text but I think it's better to cover the more cases as possible.

Comment: @Toto I concede the point there.  OP has updated their question so that may assist us as well.

Comment: The second condition can't be done with regex. regex don't do calculations.

Answer (score 1):

###### REGEX

This regex searches for a string that matches the last instance of the word `cat` followed by any number of characters that end with the word `dog`

```
\bcat\b(?!.+\bcat\b).+?\bdog\b
```

| Token | Notes |
| --- | --- |
| `(?!...)` | Negative Lookahead |
| `.` | Matches any single character |
| `+?` | Match the previous token between 1 and unlimited times (lazy) |
| `\b` | Word boundary |

##### Steps

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to bring up `Find` dialog
2. Match the following settings:
      ☐   Match Case *(Unchecked)*
      ☑   Regular Expression *(Checked)*
3. In the "Find What" field enter the RegEx
4. Click<kbd>Find Next</kbd> (or Find All)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is matching `CAT DOG DOG CAT CAT DOG`. As ask in question it should match `cat sees a shadow which can only be that of a dog`

Comment: As I said above, OP wants to match `cat sees a shadow which can only be that of a dog`. Your regex doesn't match that.